# The address of a member object is changing immediately after constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, constructor, memory-address

If you would like to see the code that causes this issue you can view and clone the project here: https://github.com/NickChapman/RuM/tree/63047e457745558403ea807534e4f5b9930cfeb8

The noteworthy bit is that inside a constructor I have (`RuMParser.cpp` line 20):

```
this->globalScope = Scope();
std::cout << &(this->globalScope) << std::endl;
```

and then immediately after the constructor finishes I have (`RuM.cpp` line 63):

```
std::cout << &(this->parser.globalScope) << std::endl;
```

The output from these is:

```
0x7fff57ac5318
0x7fff57ac6988
```

Why are they not the same? For all of the rest of time the address will remain fixed at the second value. Why does it change after leaving the constructor?

I noticed this issue when trying to establish a pointer immediately after the first print out. The pointer is to an older address the second the constructor finishes and I am baffled as to why.

My suspicion is that this has something to do with copy constructors or something of that nature.

Edit: For reference if you are trying to build the source and run you can just:

```
cmake .
make
```

then

```
./rum
```

Entering `x=1;$` will cause the program to segfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this->parser = RuMParser(tokenList);
std::cout << &(this->parser.globalScope) << std::endl;
```

First, a temporary `RuMParser` is created and this is when you get the first print. The temporary is then copy constructed into `this->parser`. That means, `globalScope` is default constructed again. Thus the different address in the later print.

Well, there are quite a few questionable/non-idiomatic things in the code, but I will stick to only what matters to this question. You can rewrite the constructor as:

```
RuMInterpreter::RuMInterpreter(): 
      tokenList(std::make_shared<std::vector<Token>>())
     ,parser(tokenList) 
{
....
}
```

Always prefer member initializer list whenever possible. It is also one of the items in effective C++ book I guess.

Comment: Without using a pointer is there a way to prevent the invocation of the copy constructor?

Comment: Construct the object the way you want it in the first place rather than assigning it after it's constructed. You can also use `boost::optional` as a "shell" that you can later construct the object into.

Comment: @NickChapman Updated the answer with what probably you should be doing.